# How to popup a context menu and click on one menu item in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and I　　need to auto popup a context menu then click one menu item on it. Is there any way to do this? I do not find any api to handle this problem.
Thanks

Comment: When you want to see some action happen on click of some menu item, why do you want to automate it? till date there is no such API.

Comment: Yeah,I want to automate it. Is there any methods other than chrome.* api?

Answer (score 0):

api url [chrome.contextMenus.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create)

demo url [Context Menus Sample (with Event Page)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/event_page.zip)

hope to help you :)

Comment: I just want to imitate the right-click action on one element, and click context menu item.